# Как запустить имеющийся код?

Tags: java, классы, syntax, main, core

Имеется код. Как его запустить в консоли `Java`.

```java
class Figure1 {  

    int x, y;

    public Figure1(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x; 
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    public void move( int dx, int dy ) {
         x =+ dx;
         y =+ dy; 
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.print("Figure: " + x + " " + y);
    }
}
```

Comment: функцию main() .

Comment: я вот нагугла. что мейн, но не  могу понять, что конкретно мейн должен содержать?

Comment: попробуйте выучить основы java

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Выведет метод `print()`.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Figure1 figure1 = new Figure1(1, 5);

       figure1.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: @DailyChinese `x =+dx;` -> ` x += dx;`

Comment: класс, спасибо большое))) я так рада, все работает!!!

Comment: @DailyChinese Выберите ответ, который Вам больше нравится, и поставьте слева от него "галочку".

Comment: Советую начать с видеоуроков на youtube для начинающих. Обращайся)

Answer (score 1):

Сначала создайте новый класс, например, под названием `Main`.
Он будет выглядеть вот так:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Figure1 figure1 = new Figure1(1, 2);

       figure1.print();
    }
}
```

Следующим шагом создайте второй класс и вставьте код, который указан ниже:

```
class Figure1 {

int x,y;

public Figure1(int x, int y) {
    this.x=x; 
    this.y=y;
}
public void move( int dx, int dy )
{
     x += dx;
     y += dy; 
     
}
public void print() {
    System.out.print("Figure:"+x+ " " + y );
}    
}
```

Посмотрите данное видео, оно поможет в обучении. [ССЫЛКА](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GLnOwDEE_A)

Comment: спасибо большое!)

Comment: Можете посмотреть на ютубе видео, которое прислал, от этого автора есть ещё несколько качественных занятий, основам научит.

Comment: спасибо за вашу помощь